# Get DateTime by Adding Minutes but consider working hours and weekends

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Interesting issue I'm facing and I just can't come up with an algorim to calculate.

Basically, what I want is to calculate a DateTime based on DateTime.Now.AddMinutes() but the Adding of minutes should take into consideration Working Hours and weekends.

In other words, if the time is currently 16:50 and i add 20 minutes, the method should return a DateTime for tomorrow morning at 08:10 (if tomorrow is not a weekend day).

I've started with some logic, but it's not complete. Does anyone have a sample which can save me a few hours of coding? This is what i've got so far:

```
public DateTime CalculateSLAFromNow(int minutes)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;                

            TimeSpan slatimeaddedon = CalculateToNextWeekDay(DateTime.Now);
            TimeSpan finalMinutesAddedon = slatimeaddedon.Add(new TimeSpan(0, minutes, 0));
            DateTime SLATime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(slatimeaddedon.TotalMinutes);
            return SLATime;
        }


        private TimeSpan CalculateToNextWeekDay(DateTime dt)
        {
           //Calculate.
        }
```

Comment: There's a lot of variables to that.  We have a `FinanceDateTime` class we use based on the market hours (stock market), but it's very dependent on our business model.  It would probably be harder to retrofit someone else's to yours than to write your own from scratch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. Friend of mine wrote the following which works 100%. Thanks J for this. Herewith the complete solution:

```
private static DateTime DoCalculation(DateTime startDate, int minutes)
{
    if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        // if the input date is a sunday, set the actual SLA start date to the following monday morning 7:00AM
        startDate = startDate.AddHours(24);
        startDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, 7, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        // if the input date is a saturday, set the actual SLA start date to the following monday morning 7:00AM
        startDate = startDate.AddHours(48);
        startDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, 7, 0, 0);
    }

    DateTime resultDate = startDate;
    for (int i = 0; i < minutes; i++)
    {
        resultDate = resultDate.AddMinutes(1);

        // it is 5PM and time to go home
        if (resultDate.Hour >= 17)
        {
            // if tomorrow is saturday
            if (resultDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                //add 48 hours to get us through the whole weekend
                resultDate = resultDate.AddHours(48);
            }

            // add 14 hours to get us to next morning
            resultDate = resultDate.AddHours(14);
        }
    }
    return resultDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static DateTime CalculateSLAFromNow(int minutes)
    {
        double days = (double)minutes / 540;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime later = now;
        while (days >= 1)
        {
            later = later.AddDays(1);
            if (later.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                later = later.AddDays(2);
            }
            days--;
        }
        days = days * 540;
        later = later.AddMinutes(days);
        if (later.Hour > 17)
        {
            later = later.AddHours(15);
        }
        if (later.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            later = later.AddDays(2);
        }
        else if(later.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            later = later.AddDays(1);
        }
        return later;
    }
```

There now it accounts for any number of minutes added (not the prettiest code, but it works)

Comment: I'd factor out the start time, and replace `minutes` by a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Thanks @NominSim . This should be fine. I think I'd have to get rid of the Add Days and add the actual hours to the next working day.. but yeah, this is a great start. Thanks

Comment: This approach only works if `minutes` is a small enough value.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis do you have another suggestion for me? Tx

Comment: I think I would create a method that calculates the next "work-free" boundary from any given `DateTime`, subtract the time until the boundary, skip to the next "free-work" boundary, repeat until you have covered all minutes.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis is right.. if I add minutes that spans over multiple weekends or even multiple days, the calculation will be way out..

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I am aware of that, didn't want to do all of the work for him, and I stated as such in the answer...

Comment: @Fox Fixed it so it should now account for any number of minutes added.

Comment: @NominSim that algorithm doesnt work mate. Have you tried it yourself? Try and add a small amount such as 10 minutes and you'll see it returns current datetime. mmmmmm, seems like i'll just have to write my own algorithm to calculate.

Comment: @Fox sorry just needed to change 'later.AddMinutes(days)' to 'later = later.AddMinutes(days)'

Comment: Thanks to everyone involved for the help and suggestions. Much appreciated